# LWC Community Navigation and api property with promise

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, api, promises

I have a community with two pages, Page1 and Page2. Standard flow is Page1 -> Page2.

When loading Page2 directly I can use it with no issues, the problem comes up when I use Page2 coming from Page1.

When navigating from Page1 to Page2, and start clicking on items on Page2, it pops error ***Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property '0' is a read-only and non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did not return its actual value (expected '[object Object]' but got '[object Object]'*** . It's like the api properties defined in Page2 cannot be used ('I'm not trying to re-write them, just read them'). This properties that are being read have an api decorator and are loaded using await/async.

The thing is this happens only when going from one page to another. If I'm standing on Page2 and refresh it directly, I can use all properties with no issues.

Any suggestions will be more than welcomed!

**UPDATE: SAMPLE CODE**

**PARENT HTML**

```
<template>
    .
    .
    .
    <template for:each={anotherList} for:item="listItem">
        <div class="slds-m-top_x-large slds-m-bottom_x-large" key={listItem.product}>
            <c-list-item some-properties all-list-products={allListProducts} more properties and events here ></c-list-item>
        </div>
    </template>
    .
    .
    .
</template>
```

**PARENT JS**

```
export default class Sample extends LightningElement {
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef
    @track myList = [] 
    @track allListProducts = [] // property passed to child

    connectedCallback() {
        this.getListFromLocalStorage()
     }

    getListFromLocalStorage = async () => {
        try {
            const info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('information'))
            if (conditions) {
                const {Id} = info.Id

                this.myList = await getList({ theId : Id })
                this.allListProducts = this.myList.products
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

**CHILD HTML**

```
<template>

<!-- not too much here, just some rendering of values and passing the same property again to the child of this child component -->

    <c-child-of-child all-list-products={allListProducts}> </c-child-of-child>

<!-- basically the property is passed from parent to 'great grand son' (going throw each component at a time) -->

</template>
```

**CHILD JS**

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    api
} from 'lwc'

export default class SampleChild extends LightningElement {
    @api allListProducts

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.allListProducts)))
    }
```

As soon as it tries to read that property, in the console.log() for example, it throws the mentioned error.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please put in some relevant code in order to get more clarity?

Comment: I've just updated the post with sample code. Thank you @PrashantKashyap

Comment: I would require more information, are both components are in both the pages?

Comment: No, both these components are just in Page2. I think the detail here is the different behavior I get in the two scenarios:

1. Using Page2 coming from Page1 -> Error in promise
2. Reloading Page2 -> Working OK

Comment: I feel this could be due to an empty object being passed till the async function finishes the execution, in your parent JS controller, convert the connectedCallback into an async function, and use await on getListFromLocalStorage(). use a flag to only render child component after getListFromLocalStorage has finished loading data

Comment: can you please put in the templates as well?

Comment: I think I've just found the bug and you're exactly right Prashant! When navigating to Page2, myList and allListProducts are 'loaded' empty. After the promise returns a value, the two properties are updated. But as cacheable=true in Apex method, I get the error because the property should be read-only. What I don't know though is why this only happens with page navigation, not with a regular page reload.

Comment: The reason I think you are right is because mapping the property to create a new copy solved issue apparently

```this.myList = await getList({ theId : Id })
                this.allListProducts = this.myList.products.map(a => a)```

Would you know why we see different behavior in each scenario ?

Comment: It did not create a new copy, it is just a new array, the elements in the object are still read only after mapping. I'm curious what you have in the templates

Comment: @PrashantKashyap I've just added some sample template